# Arduino Leonardo - "avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding"

Tags: arduino, upload

I am having issues uploading new code to an Arduino Leonardo board. This happens after uploading previous buggy code (e.g., array out of range indexing error). Once I fixed the buggy code, I can upload it to another hardware unit, but not the same unit that previously had the buggy code.

I am using [Microduino](http://wiki.microduinoinc.com/Microduino-Module_CoreUSB) and I have tried resetting the hardware (by connecting GND to RST pin), yet I still cannot upload the new code on it. How can I fix this?

See the verbose output log below:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino IDE for Microduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM5
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Comment: If resetting when the IDE says "Uploading" doesn't work, then you might need an ISP programmer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was fixed by pushing the reset button quickly after I clicked on the upload button!

Comment: lol, really, this is the only thing that worked for me! Cheers man

Comment: so weird... for me the reset also worked. It changed the com port briefly so maybe watch out for that as well.

Answer (score 8):

This could be due to the way the Leonardo/Micro bootloader works (the uploader waits for a new serial port to appear, presuming that to be the bootloader).

The official advice is to press and hold reset on the board, click upload, wait for the code to compile and for the status bar to say 'Uploading...' and then release the reset button on the board.

See here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardoMicro#toc6

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with my pro micro( using Arduino type Leonardo) , finally fixed it by NOT plugging into my USB hub and plugging directly into my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I use Arduino Leonardo from Amperka kit and I stumbled upon the same issue. I finally beat this by following the next steps (they are similar with some of the solutions present here but different in details):

1. Press and hold the reset button on the Arduino
2. Click “Upload” in the IDE
3. Await for the compiling step is done
4. Await for the “Waiting for upload port…” message
5. Release the reset Arduino button and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works connected to the computer's rear USB port, the one that is directly on the motherboard